# prettycheckable - Setting ALL labels with data of first checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Has anyone had this issue before using prettycheckable? I have a series of checkboxes or radio buttons, All of them have a different (data-label="") But when I test the page, all of the labels are using the (data-label="") from the first element.

```
 <script>
     $('input.prettyCheckable').prettyCheckable();
 </script>
```

and

```
 <input class="prettyCheckable" value="option1" id="option1" data-label="Option 1" type="radio">
 <input class="prettyCheckable" value="option2" id="option2" data-label="Option 2" type="radio">
 <input class="prettyCheckable" value="option3" id="option3" data-label="Option 3" type="radio">
 <input class="prettyCheckable" value="option4" id="option4" data-label="Option 4" type="radio">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation states, you need to call .prettyCheckable on each input.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('input:radio').each(function(){
  $(this).prettyCheckable();
 });
});
```